# Accesssing all values from same key for different dictionaries within nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary:

```
d = { 'wing': {'name': 'Ali', 'age': '19'}, 
    'scrumHalf': {'name': 'Bob', 'age': '25'},
    'flyHalf': {'name': 'Sam', 'age': '43'},
    'prop': {'name': 'rob', 'age': '33'}}
```

I want to pull out the values for `age` only to generate a list
`[19, 25, 43, 33]`

I want to do this using a for loop, and as naively as possible, as I usually find that easiest to understand.

I have managed to print all of the keys using a for loop:

```
for i in d:
    print i
    for j in d[i]:
        print j
```

but when I tried to edit it to print the values I got the error 
`NameError: name 'value' is not defined`. How can I get `'value'` to mean the value attached to a key?

Here is my edited version

```
for i in d:
    print (i[value])
    for j in d[i]:
        print (j[value])
```

I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access values in the dict with the help of the method `values()`:

```
[i['age'] for i in d.values()]
# ['19', '25', '43', '33']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [d.get(k).get('age') for k, v in d.items()]
['33', '25', '19', '43']
```

In-order to access a dictionary's value you are iterating through keys first which is correct i.e. `for i in d:`. So, in order to access value of key `i` in d, you'll need to do `d[i]` which will give you the value, for example `{'name': 'rob', 'age': '33'}` then to access the required key you'll have to access from dictionary once more i.e. `d[i]['age']`.